# Messenger call does not work in any browser on Linux

Tags: browser, mx-linux, facebook

I am using MX-Linux 21 KDE. Whenever I try to make a call on [messenger](https://messenger.com), the connection times out automatically after 3 to 4 seconds, this happens even in troubleshooting mode. I have tested this on opera, chrome and firefox and got the same result.

Can anyone tell me what the issue could be? I wish I could solve this on my own.

Comment: Does audio recording work for you at all? https://www.google.com/search?q=check+mic+online

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, yes, it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe you could use https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine instead?

Comment: I tried that before you suggested me. But unfortunately, that project is still buggy. Fonts are broken, and it is resource-hungry. And that problem I mentioned also persists here.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, the same problem arises on caprine too. It does not work out there. So I don't know where the issue might be.

Comment: I've no idea to be honest. Try kernel 5.16.3 or another distro.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, ok, I will try doing that using live-boot.